# <p:dataTable sortBy="#{factoryReturn.place}"> getPlace() method not invoked

Tags: sorting, jsf, primefaces, datatable

I have a `<p:dataTable>` in my XHTML and I want to sort it by the place integer. I however,  have checked and the `getPlace()` isn't being called.

```
<p:dataTable value="#{factoryReturnGeneralBean.awaitingInWorkShop}"
             id="awaitingInWorkShopTable" var="factoryReturn"
             sortBy="#{factoryReturn.place}">

    <p:column style="background-color: #{factoryReturn.col}">
        <f:facet name="header">
            <h:outputText value="Cal Number"/>
        </f:facet>
        <h:outputText value="CAL#{factoryReturn.calnum}"/>
    </p:column>

    <p:column style="width: 10%" >
        <f:facet name="header">
            <h:outputText value="In Workshop Date"/>
        </f:facet>
        <h:outputText value="#{factoryReturn.bookedInDate}">
            <f:convertDateTime pattern="dd/MM/yyyy"/>
        </h:outputText>
    </p:column>
</p:dataTable>
```

The method is

public int getPlace() {
        this.place = placement();
        return this.place;
    }

```
public int placement() {
    setColours();
    if (this.priority == 'h') {
        return 0;
    }

    if (this.priority == 'm') {
        return 1;
    }

    if (this.priority == 'l') {
        return 2;
    } else {
        return 3;
    }
}
```

Any idea why when I break point inside `getPlace()` it doesn't get hit when all the other methods inside the `factoryReturn` class are made and used the same way but work?

Edit:

Using PrimeFaces 3.0

Comment: Maybe it's because of this issue: https://code.google.com/p/primefaces/issues/detail?id=457

Comment: You forgot to tell PrimeFaces version. Have you checked PrimeFaces Users Guide associated with the specific PrimeFaces version you're using? Things have changed across PrimeFaces versions and the current showcase only represents 5.1.

Comment: Regardless of some answers/workarounds found over the internet, the initial sort order provided by a `<p:dataTable>` out of the box, never worked for me especially with multi-sort, since I started with its version 3.0 (not even in PrimeFaces 5.1). I simply have been discarding/avoiding it throughout my applications and never thought about since then. (I would not be surprised at all, if I missed something which is very fundamental by the way).

Answer (score 0):

PrimeFaces 3.0 is bugged and you cannot use the `sortBy` function as it doesn't work. so when you load your data into your list. using returns as the list loaded from where you get your data from

```
        List<FactoryReturn> tempList = new ArrayList<FactoryReturn>();
        for (int i = 0; i < returns.size(); i++)
        {
            char c = returns.get(i).getPriority();
            if (c == 'h')
            {
                tempList.add(returns.get(i));
            }
        }
        for (int i = 0; i < returns.size(); i++)
        {
            char c = returns.get(i).getPriority();
            if (c == 'm')
            {
                tempList.add(returns.get(i));
            }
        }
        for (int i = 0; i < returns.size(); i++)
        {
            char c = returns.get(i).getPriority();
            if (c == 'l')
            {
                tempList.add(returns.get(i));
            }
        }

        for (int i = 0; i < returns.size(); i++)
        {
            char c = returns.get(i).getPriority();
            if (c =! 'l' && c =! 'm' && c =! 'h')
            {
                tempList.add(returns.get(i));
            }
        }
        returns.clear();
        returns = new ArrayList<FactoryReturn>(tempList);
```